# How to add dates in two dates weekwise?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I have a table in which rows have dates as monday dates of the weeks. Some consecutive rows may not have consecutive weekdate and thus has gaps in between. This image will clear the situation:
[image]

As clear from the image, there is a gap between weekdates 2016-08-08 and 2016-09-05 as rows with weekdates '2016-08-15','2016-08-22','2016-08-29' are not there before '2016-09-05'.

So, how can I fill this gap with rows for all these dates and null for rest two columns?

Comment: please paste image as text

Comment: @TheGameiswar The image url is http://i.stack.imgur.com/N5EBN.png

Comment: images are blocked in my domain,same may be the case with most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tally table

- either from a physically stored [numbers table, see code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474751/5089204)
- or create one *on-the-fly* with a `CTE`.

You might try this code, which will generate a list of Mondays

```
DECLARE @start INT=0;
DECLARE @end INT=20;
DECLARE @step INT=7;

WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
,Tally AS(SELECT TOP(@end-@start +1) (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) + @start -1) * @step AS Nr FROM N3 
          CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,Nr,{d'2016-08-01'}) AS Monday 
FROM Tally
```

You can specify the count of generated rows with `@start` and `@end`, the `@step` should be 7 in your case. This will add 0, 7, 14, 21, ... to a given date (which should be a Monday in your case).

Now use a `LEFT JOIN` to combine this with your table data. This should result in a *gap-less* list of all Mondays together with values - if there are any...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(week,1,[select query]) -- In select query write the query 
                                      -- to get the date to which you need to add 1 week
```

[image]

In the above query it will take the current date i.e `2016-09-08 15:19:06.950` and add 1 week to it and give the resultant date i.e `2016-09-15 15:19:40.657`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I dont want 1 week added to any date, but I want to get all the weekddates which could fill gap between 2 dates like I shown in my example.