# Alternative to cursor when applying a list of values to a where clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What's an alternative to getting a distinct number of dates, say all the dates for September:

```
9/1/2016
9/2/2016
9/3/2016
```

and apply each value to a query. Say something like:

```
Select GuitarId,GuitarBrand
From GuitarSales
Where GuitarDate = @date
```

I don't want to use a cursor, is there an alternative to doing this?

I tried a CTE but even then I'd have to apply the cursor for each date.

Comment: lookup/temp table, then join.  preferably with indexes on both tables.

Comment: `where GuitarDate in (select date from ... )` ?

Comment: which database you are using

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where do you want to use the result of this query?

Comment: Consecutive date or free-form?

Comment: Are you looking to find all rows for a specific September (like 2016) or all Septembers? If it is a specific september you don't need to generate a list of all dates, you can do that with some simple date math.

Comment: Is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the dates for a month you can use

```
Select GuitarId,GuitarBrand
From GuitarSales
Where month(GuitarDate) = 9
and year(GuitarDate) = 2016;
```

Comment: But don't forget the year :-)

Comment: Not the most efficient way to go about this. A SARGable predicate would be better so you can utilize indexes.

Comment: @SeanLange  i know this but the OP don't show the indexs  structure or others informatio about schema, storage or performance but seems only interested  to obatin short condition .. but if you have a better where  post an you answer .. so all the community can evaluate .. it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you need a list of all dates in September. This is a quick solution to get a gapless list of all days in September: In your query you can use this as source and `LEFT JOIN` your actual data.

```
WITH RunningNumbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP(30) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS Nr
    FROM sys.objects 
)
SELECT {d'2016-09-01'}+Nr AS RunningDate
FROM RunningNumbers
```

There are many examples, how you can create a *tally table* on the fly. Small numbers (like 30 in this example) can be taken easily from any table with sufficient rows.

If you need this more often you might think about a *Numbers-Table*

- a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39387790/5089204
- create a persitant numbers table with a lot of usefull side data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474751/5089204

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an index on GuitarDate here is a way you can create a SARGable where predicate so you can still leverage the speed of using an index seek.

```
declare @date datetime = '2016-09-10' --just to demonstrate starting with September 10, 2016

select gs.GuitarId
    , gs.GuitarBrand
From GuitarSales gs
where gs.GuitarDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0) --beginning of the month for @date
    and gs.GuitarDate < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date) + 1, 0) --beginning of next month
```