# How to get weeknumber with the given conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, datepart

How can I get weeknumber of a date with Sunday as first day of the week and Start with the week that has at least four days in the new year, in short datepart equivalent of

```
 DatePart("WW", datefield, vbSunday, vbFirstFourDays)?
```

Because for example, I want 1st January 2015 to return 53 instead of 1, as the first week of 2015 has 4 days though, but starts from Thursday instead of Sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this fulfills all your requirements, but [there is `ISO_WEEK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,'20160103')
```

Which day is taken as the [*first day of the week* is dependant on `DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). (See the comments about `ISO_WEEK` and `DATEFIRST`. In case of `ISO_WEEK` this is Monday in any case...)

Test your edge-cases...

If the standard (*out-of-the-box*) mechanisms don't meet your needs you should [think about a *calendar/number-table*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474751/5089204). You can widen this by any custom column. Any *compute-this-with-some-magic-logic* approach is more work and takes more time than to set some edge-values in a table manually. Furthermore, such a table will be faster and will help you in very many related cases.

Comment: Ref: [ISO First Week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week). NB: ISO Weeks start on Monday.

Comment: @HABO, Just tested it. Thx for the hint, ISO-Week is not looking at `@@DATEFIRST`. In this case I'd use a calendar/number-table and add a column with the ISO_WEEK. This I'd modify semi-manually for some edge cases...

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo , the Idea of Calendar/number-table with adjustment in some corner cases worked for me.