# DATEPART: specifying first day of week when SET DATEFIRST cannot be used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reportserver

I am creating some reports in ReportServer (dynamic list type), one of them is retrieving info from SQL Server for events in the past week.

In SSMS, it's simple enough, I get the needed info (timewise) with

```
... WHERE DATEPART(week, event_date) = DATEPART(week, DATEADD(d, -5, GETDATE()))
```

preceded by a

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
```

statement so that Monday is set as the first day of the week.

Unfortunately, ReportServer does not accept the `SET DATEFIRST` statement as part of the query, so after leaving it out, the data returned ranges from Sunday to Saturday instead of Monday to Sunday. I cannot make global changes to the database (or server, for that matter).

How can I get round this?

Comment: The simple answer would be to deploy stored procedures that contain the `SET DATEFIRST` change. Can you coax your DBAs to allow this? Be aware that `SET DATEFIRST` is scoped to the current session so you may also want to save the values of `@@DATEFIRST` before changing it and restore the value after your query - otherwise you have the potential to affect other queries reusing the same connection.

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning but that's part of my problem: I cannot make any changes to the database unless they're really process-related; I'm afraid reporting does not fall into that category

Comment: The best idea might be to introduce a physical number/date table, which is very handsome in many places. Something along [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474751/5089204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along this using [`@@DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). This is a system variable you can use without any declaring or setting in inline/ad-hoc queries:

--This is a Sunday

```
DECLARE @OneSunday DATE='20190929';
```

--Your statement returns differently in different cultures

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT DATEPART(week, @OneSunday); --<-- returns 40
SELECT @@DATEFIRST;                --<-- returns 7  

SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT DATEPART(week, @OneSunday); --<-- returns 39
SELECT @@DATEFIRST;                --<-- returns 1
```

As you can see, the system variable `@@DATEFIRST` reflects the day's index, which is set by the culture. And you can use it for some correctional arithmetics.

```
SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT DATEPART(week, DATEADD(DAY,(@@DATEFIRST % 7),@OneSunday));

SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT DATEPART(week, DATEADD(DAY,(@@DATEFIRST % 7),@OneSunday));
```

Now both return 40.

I use `% 7` to get a `0`, where `@@DATEFIRST` returns the `7`.

Comment: thank you! You've put me on the right path. I modified your suggestion to fit my query and the following works perfectly: `DATEPART(week, DATEADD(d, CASE WHEN @@DATEFIRST % 7 = 0 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END , event_date)) = DATEPART(week, DATEADD(d, -5, GETDATE()))`

Comment: @ChrisBE I'm glad to help you. Just one tiny hint: In your construction you don't need the `%7`. You can test for `@@DATEFIRST=7`. The trick with `%` makes it easier in computations...

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the desired first day of the week and then use a week date range in your `where` clause e.g.

```
declare @FirstDayOfWeek date, @Now date = getdate();

select @FirstDayOfWeek = dateadd(day, -1*(case when datepart(weekday, @Now) > 1 then datepart(weekday, @Now)-2 else 6 end), @Now);

select *
from dbo.MyTable
where event_date >= @FirstDayOfWeek and event_date < dateadd(week, 1, @FirstDayOfWeek);
```

And of course you can also embed the calculation in the query e.g.

```
select *
from dbo.MyTable
cross join (
  select dateadd(day, -1*(case when datepart(weekday, getdate()) > 1 then datepart(weekday, getdate())-2 else 6 end), getdate()) FirstDayOfWeek
) D
where event_date >= D.FirstDayOfWeek and event_date < dateadd(week, 1, D.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Note: You could just duplicate the date calculation into the `where` clause and avoid the `join` but I dislike having duplicated calculations.

Comment: Thank you @Dale Burrell but without even trying, I can tell you that Reportserver won't allow me to DECLARE anything, no more than it allows me to SET anything

Comment: @ChrisBE are you sure? `declare` is very very different to `set` in terms of permissions. I would give it a try. It works in SSRS.

Comment: @ChrisBE and of course you don't need to declare it, you can compute it as part of the query.

Comment: @ChrisBE, Just to mention this: You can simulate a declared variable using a CTE: `WITH myVariables(VariableA) AS(SELECT 'names') SELECT * FROM myVariables v CROSS JOIN sys.objects o WHERE o.[name] like '%' +  v.VariableA  + '%'`. This will use `'names'` similar to a variable...

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted week that starts with `Monday`, you use a reference date that is `Monday` like `1900-01-01` and calculate the start and end date of a week

```
begin_of_week = dateadd(day, datediff(day, '1900-01-01', [date]) / 7 * 7, '1900-01-01')
```

and to get the end of week date,

```
end_of_week = dateadd(day, datediff(day, '1900-01-01', [date]) / 7 * 7 + 7, '1989-12-31')
```

so put that into your query ( i am assuming that your event_date may contain time component, hence, the upper condition is a `less than` `<` )

```
WHERE event_date >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, '1900-01-01', getdate()) / 7 * 7, '1900-01-01')
AND   event_date <  dateadd(day, datediff(day, '1900-01-01', getdate()) / 7 * 7 + 7, '1900-01-01')
```

Comment: There is [`@@DATEFIRST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for this...